# Cannot run Blender installed via snap on Ubuntu server

Tags: installation, linux

I installed Blender 3.4.1 on an Ubuntu 22.04 server via snap:

```sh
sudo snap install blender --classic
```

But when I try to run it:

```sh
blender -b -v
```

I get an error:

```sh
error while loading shared libraries: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix it? Isn't a snap package supposed to contain all its dependencies?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that Blender needs Xorg even if it's run with the `-b`/`--background` flag. On a server Xorg may not be installed by default, so it should be installed manually:

```sh
sudo apt install xorg
```

Since Blender installed with the `--classic` flag, it has access to the whole system and can use globally installed libs. So it doesn't have to contain all its dependencies.